# With multiple named Google Analytics trackers, pageviews are not firing

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics allows you to track multiple properties on the same page by using the "name" field when creating a tracker. The name plus a "." is then appended to the string in the first argument of calls to trigger a pageview or event for that tracker.

When using this named tracker syntax, no tracking occurred. For example:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', {'name': 'new-tracker'});
ga('new-tracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the dashes in the tracker name that caused it to not work. Switching to camelBack casing for the tracker name fixed the problem. There is nothing about allowed characters in the [current documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#name) as far as I have seen. It seems just letters and numbers should be used to be safe - i.e. one that passes a /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/ regex.